# Swashbuckle.AspNetCore: Adding multiple examples for a parameter possible?

Tags: swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I'm using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore and I would like to show multiple examples for a parameter via XML documentation. I see that the specification allows it (https://swagger.io/docs/specification/adding-examples/), but I can't seem to figure out how to do so with Swashbuckle.AspNetCore. Is it possible?

I tried the following,

1. `<example>"item 1","item 2"</example>`

   - In swagger, the example is not added.
2. `<example>["item 1","item 2"]</example>`

   - I believe this should only be used if the parameter is an array, so no go.

Comment: AFAIK there is no support for this in swashbuckle but you have to write your own operation filter to add such examples and that too you would not be able to do via xml comments but via a attribute or example provider class or something. as long as it is supported in the specification and swagger ui , it should be possible.

Comment: Try [this](https://link.medium.com/bemAjYabHtb). It does not uses xml comment but does the job. Take a look

Comment: Thanks. This got me to the right track. However, it only allow adding multiple examples for parameters in endpoints. I was looking for a way to add multiple examples for properties in the components section. Sadly after halfway implementing this in `SchemaFilter`, only did I notice that `OpenApiSchema` does not have `Examples` property. Rechecking the specification at https://swagger.io/docs/specification/adding-examples/, I found that schemas and properties does not support multiple examples.

Comment: you are correct. it is not supported for schema but only for route parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CodingMytra provided the link (https://link.medium.com/bemAjYabHtb) to the solution to my question.

Note that according to the specification at https://swagger.io/docs/specification/adding-examples/, multiple examples is only supported for parameters.

If for some reasons (like me), you want to display the examples for schema, then the only way is to display them in the the description of the property. The example below shows how to do it.

**Example Attribute Base Class**

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Parameter | AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = false)]
public abstract class SwaggerParameterExampleBaseAttribute : Attribute
{ }
```

**[Name, Value] Example Attribute Class**

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Parameter | AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = false)]
public class SwaggerParameterExampleAttribute : SwaggerParameterExampleBaseAttribute
{
    public SwaggerParameterExampleAttribute(string name, string value)
    {
        Name = name;
        Value = value;
    }

    public SwaggerParameterExampleAttribute(string value)
    {
        Name = value;
        Value = value;
    }

    public string Name { get; }
    public string Value { get; }
}
```

**Enum Example Attribute Class**

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Parameter | AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = false)]
public class SwaggerParameterExamplesFromEnumAttribute : SwaggerParameterExampleBaseAttribute
{
    public SwaggerParameterExamplesFromEnumAttribute(Type type)
    {
        if (!type.IsEnum)
            throw new ArgumentException("Must be an Enum", nameof(type));

        EnumType = type;
    }

    public Type EnumType { get; }
}
```

**Example Filter**

```
public class ExampleSchemaFilter : ISchemaFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiSchema schema, SchemaFilterContext context)
    {
        if (context.Type.IsClass)
        {
            foreach (var pi in context.Type.GetProperties())
            {
                var attribs = pi.GetCustomAttributes<SwaggerParameterExampleBaseAttribute>().ToArray();
                if (attribs?.Length > 0)
                {
                    var prop = schema.Properties.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key.Equals(pi.Name, System.StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
                    if (!prop.Equals(default(KeyValuePair<string, OpenApiSchema>)))
                    {
                        var list = new List<string>();

                        list.AddRange(attribs.OfType<SwaggerParameterExampleAttribute>().Select(x => x.Value));
                        foreach (var attrib in attribs.OfType<SwaggerParameterExamplesFromEnumAttribute>().ToArray())
                        {
                            list.AddRange(Enum.GetNames(attrib.EnumType));
                        }

                        prop.Value.Example = new Microsoft.OpenApi.Any.OpenApiString(list.First());
                        if (list.Count > 1)
                        {
                            prop.Value.Description += $"\r\n\r\n" +
                                $"The value can be:\r\n" +
                                $"- {string.Join("\r\n- ", list)}";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
public class MyClass
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This is my property
    /// </summary>
    [SwaggerParameterExample("MyExample1")]
    [SwaggerParameterExample("MyExample2")]
    [SwaggerParameterExamplesFromEnum(typeof(MyEnum))]
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

**Result in swagger UI**

```
MyClass {
  MyProperty   string
               example: MyExample1

               This is my property

               The value can be:
                * MyExample1
                * MyExample2
                * MyEnumString1
                * MyEnumString2
}
```